# MS Paint: how to enter proper text?

Tags: windows, fonts, image-editing

How do I enter normal text in [Microsoft Paint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint_(software))?

Normally I don't have any problems adding text to an image 
in Paint. But I ran into this problem:

[image]

The text is supposed to be "abcdefd" (entered in a text 
editor and pasted). The same characters appear if typed 
directly. So apparently it is using some other character 
set. How do I restore normal operation?

Platform: MS Paint 5.2, Windows XP Professional x64 SP2, 8 GB RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click in a text field and choose the "Text Toolbar" option to bring up a font selection menu.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using Wingdings or some other crazy font. When using the text tool, a toolbar should appear which will let you change the font.

Answer (score 0):

You have a symbol font, Wingdings or Webdings I believe. Change the font face.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally an answer to the question, but rather a suggestion:

A nice and free replacement for MSPaint could be [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net). It offers more and better functionalities than MSPaint.